# ionicView.leave and ionicView.enter events fire wrongly

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

Short description of the problem:

I have these two events in my controller and they both fire wrongly. my ionicView.leave event fires when i enter the controller and my ionicView.enter event fires upon leaving the controller. Its so weird. Why is this happening? Also, it only gets called when it is $rootScope and not $scope

What behavior are you expecting?

I am expecting both events to fire correctly.
Steps to reproduce:
1. Go to ur controller, add an ionicView.leave and ionicView.enter event
2. Create a function to enter and leave the controller wt the view
3. Try with $scope and $rootScope

> $rootScope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function() { console.log('on the
>   way leaving') })
>
> $rootScope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() { console.log('on
>   the way entering') })

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you need to do something wrong. I simple copied your example into a small project of me and everthing is working fine.

I need to use the $scope instead of the $rootScope but all in all it really depends on how you structure your code.